# How to name upload images from users?

Tags: php, mysql, image

I was wondering how should I name my images upload using PHP & MySQL, should I use the auto increment number as the name of the image for example, 1.gif or should I use some random numbers or something. I was thinking auto increment was better. But what would be best?

Comment: Best for what? What are your requirements?

Comment: just stick to autoincrement it's simple and hassle free

Comment: i was just wondering if its okay to use the auto increment id as the images name or should I use something else?

Comment: using an id is fine, see my answer below

Answer (score 3):

Since no one's officially offered this yet, I'd advise to simply store the file name as the database unique id, nothing more, and store the extension in the database (unless you are forcing all images to be .jpg or something, then you don't need to).

- It is always going to be a safe file name (an integer)
- It will always be unique
- No need to store the file name in the db or worry about scrubbing it.
- It will be as small as possible.

Why I would not use the user's username/id, as suggested by others:

- There's no benefit, and no reason to expose a user's id in the file name if you don't need to.
- No need to scrub it for allowed characters, which may even end up with multiple users with the same "file safe" user name.
- User names may change, so it doesn't always make sense, and you don't want to have to rename files if you want them to match.

Why I would not use the original file name in any form:

- There's no benefit.
- You have to scrub it for allowed characters.
- There will be duplicates.

Unless you are interested in vanity file names, I can't think of any reason not to just use the auto-increment id. If your DB ids are unique, your file names will be too.

If later on you do want "pretty" file names, you can use `.htaccess` to rewrite the requests, and/or output your images through a php script, which also has the benefit of checking for permissions and whatnot if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
md5(microtime())
```

?

It is pretty unique

Comment: What about just `microtime()`? That's just as unique, if not more so.

Comment: Theoretically, two users could upload an image at the same exact microsecond, plus something like `0.22362100 1316305077` makes for a bad file name. Being unique is not relative, it either is or it isn't - there is no such thing as "more" unique.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Did you notice that md5()? I think it's very rare, I can imagine someone would upload it within same second, but millisecond?

Comment: Yes, saw it - I was really replying to adlawson, and I agree - the same millisecond will *probably* never happen, but I would never use the raw microtime as a file name as he suggests. But why bother with any of this when you can use the auto-increment column value as OP suggests, which will always be unique?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: ID incrementing? No, that's a bad idea in popular image uploader with option of private images

Comment: I guess you could hash the id, but what do you mean "bad idea"? You can and should be protecting the images with `.htaccess` and running the output through a php script if you really want them to be "private", the other option (hoping no one guesses the file name) is referred to as "security through obscurity" - better than nothing but not really secure.

Comment: yes, you could, but everyone knows that number 1 is c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b

Answer (score 0):

One good way to name the images is to append a user name to an autoincrement value padded on the left with zero, such as "00000027MyPic.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a combination of an auto incrementing id and filename.

So if I upload the image my_photo.jpg and it gets stored with an id of 5, I would save it as 5_my_photo.jpg

This way, the original filename and extension are preserved and I can deliver it back to the user without the id prefix if I want to.

Answer (score -1):

if you are worried about the image being unique, store it as `time().$extention`.

I also prefer to put the user's username as a prefix, but thats just me, there is no reason to do that.

Comment: `time()` is not necessarily unique - it is very likely for two uploads to occur at the same second, and I can think of a few reasons why using someone's username in the file name could be a bad idea or even not possible.

Comment: yea well then me using the user's username in the extension does help :)

Comment: Well, for instance on Stack Overflow user names are not unique, you'd have to use the user id - and it is still possible then (although less likely) to have two uploads occur at the same second from the same account. For instance: with multiple uploads, it's possible to have several files uploaded at the same second.

Comment: fair enough, eventhough I believe its not likely for 2 images to be uploaded at the same time for a user due to the fact that the script will be running in order and it will take more than 1 second to upload an image to the server,  but you are right there is always the possibility of that happening I guess.

Comment: I have an upload queue in my CMS that typically uploads 3/4 images per second on a good day, so `username_timestamp.extension` will not be unique in that case - you'd be better of with a hashed microtime as genesis suggests.

Comment: I upped your comment because you didnt give up and explained with reasons :) but I gotta tell you that you have a well written script and a fast server :)

Comment: The server is about 10 miles from my house, so for me it's pretty fast :)